# Reading N number of rows within a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I currently have a script which reads a CSV file, and coverts a specific column into a dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv, itertools
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list)

with open('file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f) 
    for row in reader:
            for (k,v) in row.items():
                columns[k].append(v)

searches = (columns['Keyword'])
```

I want to amend the current script, so instead of reading the entire "Keyword" column, I can limit it to the top 5, 10, 15 etc. rows.

I have tried a few other post suggestions and can't seem to find one to work E.G. I have tried adding the following line, which returns an empty dict.

```
for row in itertools.islice(csv.DictReader(f), 10):
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Example of CSV output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter to break when it reaches the limit.

```
limit = 5


with open('file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f) 
    for idx, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
        for (k,v) in row.items():
            columns[k].append(v)
        if idx == limit:
            break

searches = (columns['Keyword'])
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm getting an "TypeError: 'DictReader' object is not subscriptable" error when running this however.

Comment: @JackNesbitt That's right, DictReader returns a generator, we can't use index slicing on it. So,  I've changed my code to use a counter.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? reader is a `<csv.DictReader object>`
Turn it into a list and you can slice it:

```
for rows in list(reader)[:5]:
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to just print one of the rows 5 times, rather than 5 individual rows

Comment: Not with a sample CSV I used to test it with. Please provide (a part of) the CSV file you are using.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of some of the CSV output

Comment: It's always better to use text. It is a bit difficult to copy-paste code from an image ;-)

Comment: Apologies, i'll bare that in mind on my next post :-). m0h17 resolved my issue, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have imported pandas you can use the read_csv by doing so

```py
limit = 10
rows = pd.read_csv("file.csv", nrows=limit), # use nrows to limit the first number of rows
searches = list(rows['Keyword']) # get your column as list
```